# Soundcloud Custom Player - play between different divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundcloud

I'm working with [soundcloud custom player](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-custom-player), and trying to get it to play the next song, even if it is in a different div.  I'm not incredibly familiar with js, but I believe i've located the code, I just don't know what exactly to do with it!

**JS**

```
 onSkip = function(player) {
    var $player = $(player);
    // continue playing through all players
    log('track finished get the next one');
    $nextItem = $('.sc-trackslist li.active', $player).next('li');
    // try to find the next track in other player
    if(!$nextItem.length){
      $nextItem = $player.nextAll('div.sc-player:first').find('.sc-trackslist li.active');
    }
    $nextItem.click();
  },
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="post">
    <a href="http://soundcloud.com/matas/hobnotropic" class="sc-player special">Track 1</a>
    <a href="http://soundcloud.com/matas/hobnotropic" class="sc-player special">Track 2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <a href="https://soundcloud.com/matas/on-the-bridge" class="sc-player">Track 3</a>
  </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT GENERATED HTML**

```
<div class="sc-player special">
    <ol class="sc-artwork-list">
        <li class="active">
        <img src="https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000000103093-941e7e-t300x300.jpg">
        </li>
    </ol>
<div class="sc-info">
    <h3><a href="http://soundcloud.com/matas/hobnotropic">Hobnotropic</a></h3>
    <h4>by<a href="http://soundcloud.com/matas">matas</a></h4>
    <p>Kinda of an experiment in search for my own sound. I've produced this track from 2 loops I've made using Hobnox Audiotool ( http://www.hobnox.com/audiotool.1046.en.html ). Imported into Ableton LIve! and tweaked some FX afterwards.</p>
    <a class="sc-info-close" href="#">X</a>
</div>
<div class="sc-controls">
    <a class="sc-play" href="#play">Play</a>
    <a class="sc-pause hidden" href="#pause">Pause</a>
</div>
    <ol class="sc-trackslist">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="http://soundcloud.com/matas/hobnotropic">Hobnotropic</a>
            <span class="sc-track-duration">8.09</span>
            </li>
        </ol>
</div>
```

Track 1 automatically goes into track 2, but i'd like it to go to track 3.  HELP! ;)

Comment: fiddle in that case would be nice.

Comment: @bnz i don't know how to create a fiddle for this in particular because it is using two js files.  https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-custom-player/blob/master/js/sc-player.js[/link] and https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-custom-player/blob/master/js/soundcloud.player.api.js[/link].  Any help would be SO appreciated!!!!